# Find the integral $\int _{1}^{e} (x \ln x)^2 dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

> Find : $$\int _{1}^{e} (x \ln x)^2 \;dx.$$

**My answer:**

I have tried integration by parts with $u = x^2$ and $dv = (\ln x)^2$ but I end up having the same integration another time!

I reversed the role of $u$ & $v$, but it also did not work?

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\ln x=y\implies x=e^y,dx=e^y\ dy$

$$\int_1^e(x\ln x)^2=\int_0^1e^{3y}y^2\ dy$$

Now $\dfrac{d(e^{my}y^n)}{dy}=me^{my}y^n+e^{my}ny^{n-1}$

If $\displaystyle I(n)=\int e^{my}y^n dy,$

$$mI(n)+nI(n-1)=e^{my}y^n+K$$

Here $m=3,n=2$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: make thus substitution $y =\ln\, x$ and then integrate by parts.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\expo{}}x^{\nu}\,\dd x & =
\left.{x^{\nu +1} \over \nu + 1}\,\right\vert_{\ 1}^{\ \expo{}} =
{\expo{\nu +1} - 1 \over \nu + 1}
\\[5mm] &
\textsf{Derive twice respect of}\ \nu:
\\
\int_{1}^{\expo{}}x^{\nu}\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
\totald[2]{}{\nu}\pars{\expo{\nu +1} - 1 \over \nu + 1} =
{\pars{\nu^{2} + 1}\expo{\nu + 1} - 2 \over \pars{\nu +1}^{3}}
\\[5mm] &
\textsf{Evaluate the limit}\ \nu \to 2:
\\
\int_{1}^{\expo{}}\bracks{x\ln\pars{x}}^{2}\,\dd x & =
\bbx{5\expo{3} - 2 \over 27} \approx 3.6455
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(\ln x)^2$ and $dv=x^2 \,dx$. Then $du=2(\ln x)\frac{1}{x} \, dx$ and $v=\frac{x^3}{3}$. So
$$I=\int_1^e(x \ln x)^2 \, dx=(\ln x)^2 \frac{x^3}{3}\Big|_{1}^{e}-\frac{2}{3}\int_1^e x^2 \ln x \, dx.$$
Now we will solve the integral on the right side. Call the integral as $J$. For this $u=\ln x$ and $dv=x^2 \, dx$. So $du= \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ and $v=\frac{x^3}{3}$.Then
$$J=(\ln x) \frac{x^3}{3}\Big|_{1}^{e}-\frac{1}{3}\int_1^e x^ 2\, dx=(\ln x) \frac{x^3}{3}\Big|_{1}^{e}-\frac{x^3}{9}\Big|_{1}^{e}=\frac{e^3}{3}-\left(\frac{e^3-1}{9}\right)=\frac{2e^3+1}{9}.$$
So
$$I=\frac{e^3}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2e^3+1}{9}\right)=\frac{5e^3-2}{27}$$

Comment: My final answer is different from you ..... are you sure that yours is correct ?

Comment: Mine is $\frac {6 e^3 + 3}{27}$

Comment: @hopefully I am quite sure my answer is correct.

Comment: the problem with me is your last line ..... all the previous is okay for me

Comment: @hopefully perhaps it would be better if you explain what the problem is. I am just substituting the value of $J$ in the expression obtained for $I$. If you want, you can check with any math software which can compute integrals. Although I'm 100% sure of my answer :-)

Comment: My whole integral is the integral called J of you ..... I took  the substitutions supposed in the other answers and then integrat by parts

Comment: @hopefully you are mistaken $J$ has only $x^2 \ln x$ (the log term is NOT squared) whereas your actual integral (which I am referring to as $I$) has $(x \ln x)^2=x^2 (\ln x)^2$.

Comment: thank you I can see my mistake now