# Integral of $\int_0^\infty {x^2}{e^{-3x}}\,dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty {x^2}{ e^{-3x}}\,dx$$

What I attempted was integration by parts twice, but I end with $-\frac{2}{27}$. That's obviously wrong, should be positive. I am also unsure whether or not $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^2}{e^{3t}}$$ converges to 0 or not.

Comment: That does tend to zero: exponentials beat powers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015570/find-the-integral-int-1e-x-ln-x2-dx/3015575#3015575

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-3x}\ dx$$

First compute without boundaries.

By applying u-substitution: $u=-3x$, we get $$=-\dfrac{1}{27}\int e^uu^2\ du$$
By applying Integration by parts $u=u^2,v^{\prime}=e^u$, we get
$$-\dfrac{1}{27}(u^2e^u-\int2ue^u\ du)=-\dfrac{1}{27}(9e^{-3x}x^2+6e^{-3x}+2e^{-3x})$$
Now apply the boundaries $$\left[-\dfrac{1}{27}(9e^{-3x}x^2+6e^{-3x}+2e^{-3x})\right]_0^\infty=0-\left(-\dfrac{2}{27}\right)=\dfrac{2}{27}$$ 
By L hospitals rule 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-3x}x^2 = \lim\frac{x^2}{e^3} =\lim\frac{2x}{3e^3}= \lim\frac{2}{9e^3}=0$

Comment: When you apply the boundaries, why doesn't that first term diverge? 9e^{3x}x^2 ?

Comment: @BigArsole: The first term is $9e^{-3x}x^2$ which converges to $0$.

Comment: Oh did you make a typo, because that's not written? It's fine though thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\boxed{\frac{2}{27}}$

More generally, it can be shown that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n}e^{-ax} \mathop{dx} = \frac{n!}{a^{n + 1}}.$$

Here, we have $n = 2$ and $a = 3$, so the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

using the substitution $u = 3x$ the integral becomes:
$$
I = \int_0^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{u}3\bigg)^2 e^{-u} d\bigg(\frac{u}3\bigg) \\
= \frac1{27} \int_0^{\infty} u^{3-1} e^{-u} du \\
= \frac{\Gamma(3)}{27}  \\
= \frac2{27}
$$